# Some kind of better oxygen-transport protein or something... Can you help me find it?

Tags: hematology, synthetic-biology, red-blood-cell

I remember reading about artificial or man-made, oxygen-transport protein that is somehow an improvement on hemoglobin, and that it is possibly immune to sickle-cell anemia, or something... But I forgot where I found it and what exactly it is...

Can you guys help me find it?

Comment: Is the protein HP7?

Comment: Seems like it is HP7. It would be immune to sickle cell anaemia because the disease happens because of a mutation in haemoglobin; any substitute for the diseased haemoglobin would work, including normal haemoglobin. For curing sickle cell anaemia you would need to anyway express it in RBCs. But the group who reported this protein never claimed that it is better than haemoglobin [[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3561710/) and [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3564963/)].

Comment: So, is there any oxygen transport protein that is better than hemoglobin? ... I remember reading about this where it said that it is an example where nature doesn't do the best it can, but just adequately... ... Looking that up now...

Comment: @Malandy Nothing other than HP7 turns up when I google "synthetic/artificial oxygen carrying protein". I have not heard of any protein being better than Hb. Fetal haemoglobin binds oxygen with slightly higher affinity and activation of fetal Hb in sickle cell patients is an ongoing therapeutic research.